# How to explain that different ways to execute script have different results

Tags: bash, sh

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$PATH"
[ "$UID" -eq 0 ] || exec sudo "$0" "$@"
echo "$UID"
echo "$SUDO_USER"
```

If I run this script by `./test.sh`, this is the result:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin  
./test.sh: 3: \[: Illegal number:  
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin  
./test.sh: 3: \[: Illegal number:  
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin  
./test.sh: 3: \[: Illegal number:  
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin  
...
```

And it keeps printing the same thing.

If I run by `sh test.sh`, then the result is:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin  
test.sh: 3: \[: Illegal number:  
sudo: test.sh: command not found  
And just print once. (I've installed sudo.)
```

As I know, `./` and `sh` command are the same. And `sh` is linked to dash. So how to explain this problem?

System info:

```
Linux version 5.19.0-32-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-026) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1\~22.04) 11.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #33\~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC
```

Explain the reason that `./` and `sh` have different results when executing the same script.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `./` and `sh` are the same? `sh` is the shell, a program. `./` is just part of the filename.

Comment: `UID` is not a standard variable. In particular, `dash` (which is likely what `sh` links to you on your machine) does not define it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script is recursively executing itself, because your `UID` is not set.

The difference between the methods:

`./test.sh` **executes** the file itself (if shebang is valid)
`sh test.sh` executes shell and passes file name as **argument**

The positional parameter `$0` reflects the file name of execution
`./test.sh`
`test.sh`

the latter one misses the path in file name, your script is therefore looking for non-existing file in `PATH` (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin)

you can use `realpath` to determine the file path:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$PATH"
[ "$(whoami)" = root ] || { exec sudo "$(realpath "$0")" "$@"; exit $?; }
echo "USER='$USER'"
echo "SUDO_USER='$SUDO_USER'"
```

Answer (score 1):

> how to explain this problem?

> ```
> sudo: test.sh: command not found
> ```

When you run `sh test.sh`, then `$0` is `test.sh` so then `sudo "$0" "$@"` command becomes `sudo test.sh`.

There is no such command as `test.sh` in PATH. You can run `./test.sh` or `sh test.sh` like `sudo ./test.sh` or `sudo sh test.sh`, but not plain `test.sh`.

Comment: `does the "$@" work with exec?` yes `su -c instead sudo` `sh -c "$@"` is very different from `sh -c '"$@"' -- "$@"`. Consider `(set -x ; set -- echo 123; sh -c "$@"; sh -c '"$@"' -- "$@")`